# Valid candidates for passing into .on when used as delegator

Tags: javascript, jquery

The jQuery documentation states that you need to pass in a selector as a string to the .on() method. For example:

```
$('#someEl').on('click', '.clickable', function() { /* ... */ });
```

However, it SEEMS to work when you pass in an individual node as well:

```
var someNode = getElementById('someNode');
$('#someEl').on('click', someNode, function() { /* ... */ });
```

When I tried passing in a jQuery object, it sort of failed out as far as I can tell, and treated it as a direct binding instead of a delegated binding:

```
var $someNode = $('#someNode');
$('#someEl').on('click', $someNode, function() { /* ... */ });

// seemed to act as:

$('#someEl').on('click', function() { /* ... */ });
```

So I guess the questions are:

1. Is passing in a DOM node just not a documented part of the API? Or did I miss it in the API docs?
2. Is there a benefit to caching the node (not the jQuery object-wrapped node), or does jQuery ultimately do the same amount of work? (in other words, I can assume when I pass a selector string that it parses it, finds the valid nodes, and then performs the binding... but if I provide it a nice fresh DOM node will it pass on this stage, or does it still for some reason wrap things up in jQuery before going to work?)
3. Am I wrong about the jQuery object being an invalid candidate? Did I just miss something in my testing? It seems silly that if I'm already caching jQ objects, that I'd have to supply a selector again (making it do the whole selection process again) rather than being able to use what I've already done...?

Comment: Basically, you should pass strings, and as you've noticed jQuery objects does'nt work. I did'nt know regular DOM elements worked, but I don't think that is a documented feature, so it's probably just a fluke that you shouldn't rely on. The event is bound to `#someE1`, and the string passed is really just a filter.

Comment: If you pass a specific DOM node – then I don’t think that could be called using .on as delegator any more …

Comment: To answer #3: if you already have a jq object, delegating doesn't make sense. Just do `jqobj.on('click', callback)`, or `jqobj.click(callback)`.

Comment: I suspect that the implementation does something like `if ($(e.target).is(theSelectorParam))`, so that'd be why a DOM node works.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy replies. CBroe, why not? The listening is still being delegated. bfavaretto, delegating the listener solves a problem that cannot be solved by direct binding. I originally had direct binding, but had to change to delegation.

Comment: What was the problem you solved by changing to event delegation? I would think that if you already have a reference to a DOM node, you could just attach the event handler to it directly instead of using delegation. The usual reasons to use event delegation are (1) to handle events on a DOM subtree that doesn't yet exist when you attach the handler or may be replaced later, or (2) when there are a multitude of elements you want to handle events for, e.g. every cell in a large table.

Comment: Michael and bfavaretto, you are both correct after all. I'm updating a bunch of listeners that need delegation, and the jQuery object that I cache wouldn't actually work even if I could pass it in. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To answer your main question, no, selectors are supposed to be a string, or `undefined`. What you're seeing is a quirk of how jQuery tries to guess which calling convention you are using - more on this in a bit.
2. There's no way to pass a DOM element instead of a selector, sadly. If `delegate` is the element that your handler was bound to, and `target` is the element that fired the event, jQuery will always search `delegate`'s descendants using the selector provided, and check if `target` is in the matched selection. If jQuery allowed some way to pass DOM nodes instead of a selector, there definitely would be a performance benefit.
3. Well, in the usage `$('#someEl').on('click', '.clickable', handler)` you've never selected elements matching `.clickable`, and neither would jQuery at that stage, so you're not doing the work doubly there.

You can call `.on()`in multiple ways, especially since there are multiple optional parameters(selector, data).

When you call `.on(type, notAString, handler)` jQuery assumes you are using the calling convention: `.on(type, data, handler)` - which it translates to `.on(type, undefined, data, handler)`.

Here is a demonstration of what your suggested calls do:
http://jsfiddle.net/BGSacho/HJLXs/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="someEl">
    <div id="someNode" class="clickable">Click me!</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function display(event) {
        console.log("event.currentTarget", event.currentTarget);
        console.log("event.delegateTarget:", event.delegateTarget)
        console.log("event.data:", event.data); 
    }
    $('#someEl').on('click', ".clickable", function (event) {
        console.log("I am .on(type, selector, fn) - my currentTarget should be .clickable and my delegateTarget should be #somEl - this demonstrates that jQuery is using the event delegation mechanism. I have no data bound to my event.");
        display(event);
    });

    $('#someEl').on('click', document.getElementById('someNode'), function (event) { 
        console.log("I'm .on(type, data, handler) - my currentTarget should be #someEl because I'm not using a delegation mechanism. I also have some data bound.")
        display(event);
    });

    $('#someEl').on('click', $('#someNode'), function (event) {
        console.log("I'm still .on(type, data, handler)");
        display(event);
    });
});
```

They might all seem to work because you don't use `this`(aka `event.currentTarget`) in your handling code. I'm not sure why you are getting different results with a jQuery object and a DOM node.

Answer (score 3):

Delegation serves two purposes:

- Setting a single event handler on a parent element for multiple children that share the same logic when the event is triggered. This is supposed to consume less memory, but should only make a noticeable difference when used to replace a large number of individual event handlers. I suspect this is what you're trying to achieve.
- Defining event handler for elements that do not exist in the DOM at the time of the binding.

Now, to answer your questions:

1. Passing a DOM node is not documented, so it shouldn't be used. Although you said it works, jQuery is fooling you. By looking at [the source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L730), it only seems to work because of event bubbling, but the `this` value inside the handler will be the container (see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EWUbs/)).
2. You said:

   > I can assume when I pass a selector string that it parses it, finds the valid nodes, and then performs the binding

   That's a wrong assumption. You're always binding to the element (or elements) you're calling `.on` at. The selector you pass is only used to check if it matches the event object's `currentTarget` property, which is provided by the browser.
3. The same I said in #2 applies here: jQuery won't select anything based on the selector you passed, it will just check the currentTarget against that selector.

Comment: This partially overlaps Sacho's answer, but since I was already in the middle of the answer when that was posted, I decided to post mine anyway.

Comment: both excellent answers, and both useful. I'll share some love to Sacho as a new member, but if I could accept both, I would. ;)

Comment: @GregPettit I'm glad to help, and I'd accept Sacho's answer too! :)